# Inline T-SQL OR subquery

Tags: t-sql, ado.net

Trying to figure out what would be the most efficient approach to use a subquery in an inline SQL statement. Inline SQL is not something I have much experience with, but I have no choice at my organization alas.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.VW_RMISPayment
WHERE ProcDate BETWEEN '7/2/2018' AND '3/8/2019' 
  AND Status = 'P' 
  AND Fund = '359' 
  AND Amount > 0 
  AND (BatchNotate = 'B' OR BatchNotate IS NULL)
ORDER BY ProcDate, Amount
```

How could I parameterized the `(BatchNotate = 'B' OR BatchNotate IS NULL)` part?

My variable passed in as a `List<string>`, but I could change it to be anything. I'm just not sure how I can create this subquery from my variable

```
if (BatchNotate.Count() > 0)
{
    query += " AND BatchNotate= @BatchNotate";
}

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNotate", batchNotate);
```

Comment: You may want to study up on _table-valued parameters_ [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). Then you could use something like `... where ... and ( exists ( select 42 from @BatchNotations as BN where BN.BatchNotate = VW_RMISPayment.BatchNotate ) or VW_RMISPayment.Batch_Notate is NULL ) ...` where `@BatchNotations` is a table-valued parameter with one row for each value you want to process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Neither of those worked for what I'm after. Here is what I ended up doing. It's kinda hacky, but it works.

```
 public static string AddParametersOR<T>(SqlParameterCollection parameters,
                                string fieldName,
                                string pattern,
                                SqlDbType parameterType,
                                int length,
                                IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    if (parameters == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters");
    if (pattern == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("pattern");
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    if (!pattern.StartsWith("@", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        throw new ArgumentException("Pattern must start with '@'");

    var parameterNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        var parameterName = parameterNames.Count.ToString(pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string parameterWithFieldName = string.Empty;
        if (item.ToString().ToUpper() == "NULL")
        {
            parameterWithFieldName = string.Format("{0} IS NULL", fieldName);
        }
        else if (item.ToString().ToUpper() == "NOTNULL")
        {
            parameterWithFieldName = string.Format("{0} IS NOT", fieldName);
        }
        else
        {
            parameterWithFieldName = string.Format("{0}= {1}", fieldName, parameterName);
        }
        parameterNames.Add(parameterWithFieldName);
        parameters.Add(parameterName, parameterType, length).Value = item;
    }

    return string.Join(" OR ", parameterNames.ToArray());
}
```

Usage:

```
if (batchNotate.Count() > 0)
 {
    query += " AND ({@BatchNotate})";
 }

string batchNotateParamNames = SqlHelper.AddParametersOR(cmd.Parameters, "BatchNotate", "@B0", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1, batchNotate);

cmd.CommandText = query.Replace("{@BatchNotate}", batchNotateParamNames);
```

Depending on how many items are in your list the output will look like this:

(BatchNotate= 'B' OR BatchNotate= 'N' OR BatchNotate IS NULL)

If it finds "NULL" or "NOTNULL" it will replace these with IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Comment: this solution is ripe for an SQL injection attack

Comment: Please explain further why ??? AddParameters is limiting the param to Varchar(1) - So a attack is going to take place with 1 character ?

Comment: sure -- if it is called with field name set to `1=1); DROP TABLE dbo.VW_RMISPayment; --`  and item set to null or notnull

Comment: I can see that however fieldName is set programmatically and not accessible to the end-user.

Comment: I question that -- many injection attacks are performed by changing configuration files and such.  You should not be taking any variable and insertiting it into a query

Comment: The potential for a injection attack is not the same as a injection attack. Depending on the context a injection attack is very real. I'm gonna go with using a bit of common sense and moving along with my solution. Pretty sure I can avoid setting up a variable in a config file or some other wildly implausible scenario. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: or you could use best practices and solve the problem the way I suggested using a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.VW_RMISPayment
WHERE ProcDate BETWEEN '7/2/2018' AND '3/8/2019' 
  AND Status = 'P' 
  AND Fund = '359' 
  AND Amount > 0 
  AND BatchNotate = COALESCE(@BatchNotate, BatchNotate)
ORDER BY ProcDate, Amount
```

Comment: This does not make sense to me the `COALESCE(@BatchNotate, NULL)` has no functionality.

Comment: I edited my answer. Does that make more sense? It is very possible I am not understanding the question properly.

Comment: Yes @Isaac that fixes the bug, I'm not sure it is the functionality the OP wants but at least it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
BatchNotate = COALESCE(@inVariable,'B')
```

If the variable (@inVariable) is null then it will "default to B.

If it is something else it will compare against that.